# Button is not visible in ion-item when combined with inputs

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an `ion-list` of food items to display wrapped in an `ion-item`, each of them is editable with three `input` fields (name, amount, unit), plus I would like to have a delete `button` at the left side of the row.

The inputs appear nicely within `ion-item` but I can't make the `"trash"` icon button to show up.

If I remove all the inputs, the button shows up.

What should I do to make both appear? Is it possible?

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JvHNEISfUCwcnujDB2jg?p=preview

Code:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>

      <button ion-button icon-only clear small>
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <ion-input type="text" value="peanut"></ion-input>
      <ion-input type="number" value="1"></ion-input>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-option>oz</ion-option>
        <ion-option>cup</ion-option>
        <ion-option>glass</ion-option>
        <ion-option>piece</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ion-col` and `ion-row` seemed to help, I wonder if this is the right way?

```
<ion-row>

  <ion-col>
    <button ion-button icon-only clear small>
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </button>

  </ion-col>

  <ion-col>
    <ion-input type="text" value="peanut"></ion-input>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-input type="number" value="1"></ion-input>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option>oz</ion-option>
      <ion-option>cup</ion-option>
      <ion-option>glass</ion-option>
      <ion-option>piece</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```